# java wsimport problem with wsdl (jax-ws)

Tags: java, jax-ws, wsimport

Can someone help me what is wrong with WSDL file.

```
wsimport -d test uri_to_my_wsdl
parsing WSDL...


[WARNING] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ns1:HeaderType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
  line 27 of uri_to_my_wsdl=anotherWS.wsdl#types?schema2

[ERROR] A class/interface with the same name "some_pkg.ObjectFactory" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.


[ERROR] (Relevant to above error) another "ObjectFactory" is generated from here.
  line 72 of uri_to_my_wsdl=anotherWS.wsdl

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.util.Util.equals(Util.java:56)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.util.CodeModelClassFactory.createClass(CodeModelClassFactory.java:119)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.util.CodeModelClassFactory.createClass(CodeModelClassFactory.java:66)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.generator.bean.ImplStructureStrategy$1.createClasses(ImplStructureStrategy.java:67)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generateClassDef(BeanGenerator.java:392)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.getClazz(BeanGenerator.java:424)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.<init>(BeanGenerator.java:191)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generate(BeanGenerator.java:164)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.model.Model.generateCode(Model.java:275)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:240)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.api.impl.s2j.SchemaCompilerImpl.bind(SchemaCompilerImpl.java:74)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.JAXBModelBuilder.bind(JAXBModelBuilder.java:123)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildJAXBModel(WSDLModeler.java:2234)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.internalBuildModel(WSDLModeler.java:176)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.processor.modeler.wsdl.WSDLModeler.buildModel(WSDLModeler.java:122)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.wscompile.WsimportTool.run(WsimportTool.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:111)
    at com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport.main(WsImport.java:41)
```

Because WS is not public I can not post here real path to WSDL.
I can send it to you by email or some other private message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely ignore the warnings. I am doing the same for my WSDL's as the generated stubs contains what I need.

Regarding Error it clearly says that there is a duplicate ObjectFactory in the WSDL.
*Please customize the scheme using schema similar to the one below.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<bindings 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl"
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
version="2.0">    
  <bindings schemaLocation="my.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
     <bindings node="xsd:complexType[@name='MyObject']">
            <jaxb:property name="MyObjectNewName"/> 
     </bindings>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Comment: I was referring to "[WARNING] src-resolve:" in your first post. For the error as I mentioned you have "ObjectFactory" defined many times.

Comment: OK. Agree. But what can I do about "ObjectFactory"? I know there is some kind of jaxb mapping file but I haven't found out how to write it. Some examples?

Comment: Have edited my answer to add the customization details. you have to use -b option to include this when generating stubs.